# Entity Framework Core 6 - ignoring annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I want to create a migration with EF Core 6 and I'm getting an error because in table in column password I already have hash string of password which is 32 chars long but my model has an annotation for max length = 20.

My question is: how can I make the migration ignore the `StringLength` annotation?

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Password length must be between 3 and 20 characters long.")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Error:

> Value too long for type character varying(20)

Database used is Postgres

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  When you create the migration?  When you apply the migration?

Comment: Don't bind your model's password hash property to your UI clear text password property. In fact, don't bind your model directly at all. Create a view model and bind that.